# Is it possible to add Edit functionality to this Todo App made using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I have created a Todo List app successfully to some extent.
My constructor function of `TodoList` is as follows:

```
class TodoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '',
      todoList: [{ id: 1, content: "Call Client" },
      { id: 2, content: "Write Log" }] }

      this.onChangeValue = this.onChangeValue.bind(this);
      this.onAddItem = this.onAddItem.bind(this);
  }
```

The remaining body of `TodoList` has **Add Item** functionality, by using two methods `onChangeValue` and `onAddItem`

```
  onChangeValue = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  onAddItem = () => {
    if (this.state.value !== '') {
      this.setState(state => {
        const todoList = state.todoList.concat({ id: state.todoList.length + 1, content: this.state.value});
        return {
          todoList,
          value: '',
        };
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const listItems = this.state.todoList.map((todo) =>
      <ListItem key={todo.id} id={todo.id} content={todo.content}/>
    )
    return <>
      <ul className="todo-list">
        {listItems}
      </ul>
      {/* <AddItem/> */}
      <div className="add-item">
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onChangeValue}/>
        <button type="submit" onClick={this.onAddItem}>Add Item</button>
      </div>
    </>
  }
}
```

**Delete** functionality and **Mark as read** functionality are created in the `ListItem` component using methods `handleChange` and `handleDeleteClick`.

```
class ListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { done : false, editing : '', deleted : false }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleDeleteClick = this.handleDeleteClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({done: event.target.checked})
  }

  handleDeleteClick() {
    this.setState({ deleted : true })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.deleted === false) {
      return <li className="list-item">
        {/* special class is added to the paragraph to strike the text when marked as done */}
        <p className={this.state.done ? 'done' : ''}>{this.props.content}</p>
        <ul className="actions">
          <li>
            <label htmlFor={'item_' + this.props.id}>Mark as done</label>
            <input name={'item_' + this.props.id} id={'item_' + this.props.id} type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </li>
          <li>
            {/* Edit button is disabled once the task is marked as done */}
            { this.state.done ? <button type="button" disabled>Edit</button> : <button type="button">Edit</button> }
          </li>
          <li><button type="button" onClick={this.handleDeleteClick}>Delete</button></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Now the only thing remaining is the **edit** functionality which I cannot figure out if it's possible or not.

The source code of my application can be found in this codepen:
https://codepen.io/blenderous/pen/rNeywyZ

Comment: It's definately possible, but you need a place to take the new title as an input. You could do it by swapping out the add component, with an edit component. You could also swap out the titles with an input field. Not sure if you want actual code examples or just some guidance in the right direction?

Comment: It would be useful if you could share some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create an `onEditItem` method inside the `TodoList` item and pass this method to each `ListItem`. This method would receive an `id` and a `newContent` values to process the updates.

```js
// TodoList component
...

onEditItem = (id, newContent) => {
  const newTodoList = this.state.todoList.map((todo) => {
    // return todo.id !== id ? todo : { ...todo, content: newContent }

    // not same id? leave as is
    if (todo.id !== id) {
      return todo;
    }

    // update content with the newContent value
    return { ...todo, content: newContent };
  });

  this.setState({ todoList: newTodoList });
};
```

Then on our `ListItem`, we'll create an `handleEditClick` method that will handle the click event for our edit button.

```js
// ListItem component
...

handleEditClick() {
  const { id, content } = this.props;

  // prompt to edit the current content
  const newContent = prompt("Edit:", content);

  // call the TodoList editTodo passing the id and the new content
  // of the current todo
  this.props.editTodo(id, newContent);
}
```

Now we'll use this method on our edit button like so

```js
...

<button
  type="button"
  disabled={this.state.done} // disabled once the task is marked as done
  onClick={this.handleEditClick}
>
  Edit
</button>
```

[image: Edit lucid-sara-py8c7]

Comment: Yes, it works! I would like to know one thing though. What does this line do ```todo.id !== id ? todo : { ...todo, content: newContent }``` I know it's the spread operator but does ```...todo``` mean ```id``` that is being edited?

Comment: I updated my answer with comments, please check it out :)